# Finding the Index Position Based on Where a Cell Value Falls Within a Range of Cell Values

Tags: google-sheets, match

**The Challenge:**
I have prices (Col A) that I need to get a corresponding margin (Col E) for based on where these prices fall within a range of price values (Col D) e.g. $5500 falls between $7500 and $4500 and it should get the margin of 15%

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1yufKelntHTQISr_S2oDuObDYQ0azWmK5t45XuNBVxVA/edit#gid=549083581

Answer (score 0):

**The Solution:**
Use the MATCH function and pass "-1"  as the third parameter so that the ["smallest value greater than or equal to the search_key"](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093378?hl=en) is returned

```
 MATCH(A2,$D$2:$D$11,-1)
```

and since the "-1" parameter makes the MATCH function start from the top of the list i.e. descending order, and we want the index of the price range value below the "smallest value greater than or equal to the search_key" we add +1 to access the next row down. Then this incremented index is passed to the INDEX function to get the corresponding margin at the same index position.

```
=INDEX($E$2:$E$11,MATCH(A2,$D$2:$D$11,-1)+1)
```